# NoSuchMethodError using JNA User32 platform map

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jna, user32

I received the following error on the first attempt of using the User32.Instance:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
>     at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.(User32.java:48)

whilst trying to run a JNA pre-defined mapping of the Windows User32 class functions.

I tried running the following code:

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null,"new 2 - Notepad++");
User32.INSTANCE.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
```

Do I have to declare my own Interface or am I able to use the User32 JNA mapping located in jna-platform? What am i doing wrong?

Edit: The error is on this line from the com.sun.jna.platform.win32.user32:

```
User32 INSTANCE = Native.load("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```

Comment: You certainly don't have to write your own interface, however you can if you wish to use win32 or other (e.g. psapi) functions that are not pre-defined. I don't know why it's not working, I can only wildly guess that the embedded JNA dll cannot be linked at runtime.

Comment: The `load` method was introduced in JNA 5.0.0. Is it possible that you're using an old JNA version or that some old version is lingering somewhere which gets loaded and throws an exception because the method is not there?

Comment: Actually, you probably just have a new version of `jna-platform` but and old version of `jna`. Update your `jna` dependency.

Comment: Got something similar but with both libraries being 5.0.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982008/nosuchmethoderror-in-jna-platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this bug by compiling against an old `jna` package (pre-5.0.0) and a new `jna-platform` package (5.0.0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.<clinit>(User32.java:48)
    at sandboxjava.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

The issue is that JNA deprecated the `Native.loadLibrary` method in version 5.0.0 and introduced the `Native.load` method. The newer `jna-platform` package uses the new method, but because the `jna` package is an older version, the `load` method simply does not exist in the package.

You should either upgrade the `jna` package to 5.0.0 (latest at the time of writing), or downgrade `jna-platform` to a pre-5.0.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

Update the maven using below dependency, It worked for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: indeed this worked for me. most recent version is still working, so it could be good to update your answer

<version>5.6.0</version>

Answer (score 1):

In my project, this error occurs when the following three dependency exist simultaneously. I move the tess4j dependency to the last and it works.

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
           <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
           <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
           <version>4.4.0</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>${project.basedir}\src\resources\lib\opencv\jna- 
           4.4.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jna.paltform</groupId>
            <artifactId>paltform</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}\src\resources\lib\opencv\jna-platform-4.4.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```