# NoSuchMethodError in jna-platform

Tags: java, jna, java-10

I wanna make a new release of the application but when starting it it throws NoSuchMethodError

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32.<clinit>(Shell32.java:45)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32Util.getFolderPath(Shell32Util.java:54)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32Util.getFolderPath(Shell32Util.java:71)
    at com.faforever.client.preferences.PreferencesService.<clinit>(PreferencesService.java:78)
    at com.faforever.client.FafClientApplication.main(FafClientApplication.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Similar to
[NoSuchMethodError using JNA User32 platform map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217390/nosuchmethoderror-using-jna-user32-platform-map)
However I do have version 5.0.0 of both libaries.

It is about this project https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client it uses gradle as a build tool...

Also I decompiled the installed program and found the method that java claims is not present in the jna libary. Which I find super weird.

Also I check no other dependency has a dependency on jna.

But the thing that is the strangest is it work when I run it all from intelij (oracle jdk 10) but then if I build the installer(openjdk 10 on travis) it does not (same machine).

Also it worked before and we did not change anything about the code related to jna nor the library version. What might have changed is the openjdk version travis uses, but I can not see how that would be related.

Does anybody have an idea what might cause this....

This is the actual code that fails:

```
Paths.get(Shell32Util.getFolderPath(ShlObj.CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA), "FAForever")
```

Even though I thik it is not the problem...

This is the jvm log https://drive.google.com/file/d/11RpxvFubYM7vCoAE-Kx_6EkIKADPQofE/view?usp=sharing

Of which this is probably the important part :

```
[3.689s][debug][class,resolve               ] com.sun.jna.Native java.lang.Object (super)
[3.689s][debug][class,resolve               ] com.sun.jna.Native com.sun.jna.Version (interface)
[3.689s][debug][class,resolve               ] com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32 com.sun.jna.Native Shell32.java:45 (explicit)
[3.689s][debug][protectiondomain            ] Checking package access
[3.689s][debug][protectiondomain            ] class loader: a 'jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader'{0x00000000ee70de08} protection domain: a 'java/security/ProtectionDomain'{0x00000000ef103908} loading: 'com/sun/jna/Native'
[3.689s][debug][protectiondomain            ] granted
[3.689s][trace][protectiondomain            ] pd set count = #1
[3.689s][debug][class,resolve               ] com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32 com.sun.jna.Native Shell32.java:45
[3.689s][info ][stacktrace                  ] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, 12
[3.689s][info ][exceptions                  ] Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000000ef00dd70}: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;> (0x00000000ef00dd70) 
thrown [t:/workspace/open/src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 741]
for thread 0x00000000031a5000
```

Probably the discord library I added also contains jna, see log from jvm:

```
[3.689s][info ][class,load                  ] com.sun.jna.Native source: file:/E:/DownlordClient%20RC/Downlord's%20FAF%20Client/lib/discord-rpc-1.6.2.jar
```

Comment: I think it would be better to open new issue on the project github page, since this is looks like a problem with the project and not with a code you wrote

Comment: If you ask me it is not gonna be a problem with jna library because as I said when I decompile I can find the method that seems to be missing

Comment: Or u mean the program that throws the error... Yeah I am the maintainer opening an issue wont help :D

Comment: I see, you are the maintainer of `downlords-faf-client`? I thought you're external user. in that case can you post also the code which fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NoSuchMethodError` related to JNA is almost always related to having an older version of JNA somewhere in your dependency list, even if you also have the current version.

Your comment here gives the hint:

> Probably the discord library I added also contains jna, see log from jvm

Looking at that library's POM we see:

```
<name>DiscordRPC</name>
<version>1.6.2</version>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

So you are likely in a situation where Gradle's dependency resolution has chosen to use the older `jna` even though you have both available, and you likely have `jna-platform` version 5.0.0 and `jna` version 4.5.1.

You should [update your build script to force](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) use of version 5.0.0 (or more recent) for both `jna` and `jna-platform`.

Comment: I am trying to shade the discord library correctly but it seems to be really hard idk.
https://github.com/Vatuu/discord-rpc/pull/35